# React Native: borderRadius and padding styling for nested text

Tags: android, css, react-native, styles, text-styling

I want to apply a different borderRadius and padding styling to nested texts, but as far as I could understand this is not supported by react native yet. Is there a workaround for this ?

What I tried so far is :

```
     <Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderRadius: 12,
          }}>
          Text1
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            borderRadius: 12,
          }}>
          Text2
        </Text>
      </Text>
```

Expected Result: Text with different backgrounds and with a borderRadius.

Actual Result: backgrounds are differnet but no borderRadius is applied

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in the text style

```
<View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        padding: 10
      }}>
     <Text>Text1</Text>
    </View>
```

Comment: I added it as you said but nothing changed. It would be nice of you if you elaborate more about this solution if you have tried it and it worked for you.

Comment: Hi @kendhia sorry for the confusion, you can try wrap the <Text>Text1</Text> with the <View>, and in the view you can puth the code with style border like this:

<View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#fff',
            padding: 10
          }}>
         <Text>Text1</Text>
        </View>

Hope this can help you. (Code in the answer edited)

Comment: hi @massam, I think you misunderstood the question. The two text views are having different styling! What you're suggesting is totally something else, the question is how to set different styling for nested texts! Thanks for the try though